# Alternative to use ExternalDataEventArgs on WF4

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I'm upgrading a StateMachine WorkFlow from 3.0 to 4.0, I also review the guidance that WF Team shipped last year, but I never heard about changes on some classes that inherits from ExternalDataEventArgs, I have to remain using the System.WorkFlow.Activities namespace for it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything using ExternalDataEventArgs and the like was a thin wrapper around WF3 queues. The WF3 queue API is replaced with the WF4 bookmarks. So create a bookmark in your activities and resume it with a single piece of data that is send into the activity when it resumes.